# parsing json feeds into iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i was trying to parse public json flickr feed into iphone.i m getting an error..

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x4b43100 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
).....
```

below is the json feed:

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=hackdayindia&lang=en-us&format=json.....

i d be so greatful if you guys could help me out[image]

Comment: That is not valid JSON input. It probably will be if you remove the leading `jsonFlickrFeed(` and trailing `)`. When having problems with JSON parsers, check whether your JSON input is valid via http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i tried jsonlint ...and it shows error for even working  json feeds...anyway thanks man..i was wondering...it could be the paranthesis....anyway ill giv atry

Comment: I’ve never found a situation when jsonlint.com fails to validate valid data. It’s not only the parentheses you need to remove — you must also remove `jsonFlickrFeed` as well.

Comment: i am not able to modify it since the file is in server..is der a way to remove the paranthesis or anyother way will be much apreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your response data is not valid JSON because of the `jsonFlickrFeed(` … `)` callback returned by the Flickr API. In order to obtain valid JSON, add `nojsoncallback=1` to your query. Using your example, the corresponding URL is:

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=hackdayindia&lang=en-us&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

If you use the response from the URL above in http://jsonlint.com, it’ll tell you it’s valid JSON.

`nojsoncallback` is documented in http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

---

A quick example of how to read that response. The top level element of the JSON string is an object, which is usually mapped to a dictionary by JSON parsers:

```
// Obtain the JSON string from Flickr API
NSString *jsonString = …;

// Parse the JSON string into a dictionary
// (in this example, via SBJSON)
NSDictionary *responseObject = [jsonString JSONValue];

// The dictionary has an entry called "items", which is an array
NSArray *items = [responseObject objectForKey:@"items"];

// Iterate over the items. Each item is an object, hence a dictionary
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    // Each item dictionary has an entry called "author_id", which is a string
    NSString *authorId = [item objectForKey:@"author_id"];

    // Log the author id
    NSLog(@"author_id = %@", authorId);
}
```

Comment: could u tell me how u were able to modify the code above..and put it back to the server...i m a noob

Comment: @user I’ve appended `&nojsoncallback=1` to your original URL after having read that Flickr API page about JSON responses. Flickr servers test if the URL contains `nojsoncallback=1` and, if it does, they remove that callback function that wraps the JSON response.

Comment: @Bavarious:i was able to get the parsed json feed in my simulator...but  still got the (.. )left in the items array....i ve tagged my printScreen above..cud u help me out

Comment: @user Those parentheses are how Cocoa logs arrays (aka NeXTSTEP format). They aren’t part of your JSON string, and in fact they mean that you’ve been able to parse the response from Flickr API.

Comment: @Bavarious:i m getting this error "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" if i try to parse the elements inside the item array on the above printScreen..i m getting dis error and thought probalby the ( ) could be the problem...i used dis syntax....NSString *string=[jsonArray objectForkey:@"author_id"]; am i doing write...cud u help me out

Comment: @user I’ve edited the answer to show how to parse that JSON response from Flickr.

Comment: @Bavarious:thanks man its worked...think am buggin u a lot..jst one last quest.i used nojsoncallback=1 for another flickr public feed.. it removed de unwanted braces...and u r right...but when tested in jsonlint it shows error here is the url:     http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1

Comment: @user jsonlint.com says http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1 is valid JSON.

Comment: @Bavarious:it worked after 2 to 3 tries...thanks man...had nice time....sure do help me in future

Comment: @user were you able to figure out the problem for the public flickr feed? It works intermittently even after adding nojsoncallback=1. I have to put the response in jsonlint and it points issues at particular key value pairs e.g. "description", "title" and "author", once I remove those lines, it becomes valid! also it doesn't point to each object in an array for these 3 fields...