# Consuming JSON Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing code to consume JSON.

```
   func setup() {

        if let flickrURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=texas&tagmode=any&format=json") {

            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(flickrURL,
                completionHandler: { (data :NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    let result = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                    var error:NSError? = nil

                    if let jsobObject :AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&error) {

                        println("\(error?.description)")

                    }

                    println("\(result)")

            }).resume()
        }
    }
```

I am constantly getting the following error:

```
Optional("Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)\" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7ff4a2d1bdc0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}")
```

I validated the json on different websites and some place it says valid and other it says not valid. I am confused!

This is the resulting JSON which is invalid.

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged texas",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/texas/",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2015-04-11T21:32:21Z",
    "generator": "https://www.flickr.com/",
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 132 HDR",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/17087559606/",
            "media": {
                "m": "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8786/17087559606_c6c3108eae_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-04-11T13:16:36-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/ericmorton/\">ericmorton<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/17087559606/\" title=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 132 HDR\"><img src=\"https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8786/17087559606_c6c3108eae_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 132 HDR\" /><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2015-04-11T21:32:21Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (ericmorton)",
            "author_id": "31408561@N00",
            "tags": "texas hdr bluebonnets muleshoebend"
        },
        {
            "title": "Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 095 HDR",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16493362113/",
            "media": {
                "m": "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8805/16493362113_0b6910ccb2_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-04-11T13:09:22-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/ericmorton/\">ericmorton<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16493362113/\" title=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 095 HDR\"><img src=\"https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8805/16493362113_0b6910ccb2_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 095 HDR\" /><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2015-04-11T21:30:53Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (ericmorton)",
            "author_id": "31408561@N00",
            "tags": "texas hdr bluebonnets muleshoebend"
        },
        {
            "title": "Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 105 HDR",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16925716248/",
            "media": {
                "m": "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8749/16925716248_9f2dcdf265_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-04-11T13:12:41-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/ericmorton/\">ericmorton<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16925716248/\" title=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 105 HDR\"><img src=\"https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8749/16925716248_9f2dcdf265_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"165\" alt=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 105 HDR\" /><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2015-04-11T21:31:10Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (ericmorton)",
            "author_id": "31408561@N00",
            "tags": "texas hdr bluebonnets muleshoebend"
        },
        {
            "title": "Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 090 HDR",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16906114977/",
            "media": {
                "m": "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7722/16906114977_7e369312cb_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-04-11T13:08:56-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/ericmorton/\">ericmorton<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16906114977/\" title=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 090 HDR\"><img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7722/16906114977_7e369312cb_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"157\" alt=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 090 HDR\" /><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2015-04-11T21:30:36Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (ericmorton)",
            "author_id": "31408561@N00",
            "tags": "texas hdr bluebonnets muleshoebend"
        },
        {
            "title": "Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 127 HDR",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16927325659/",
            "media": {
                "m": "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7587/16927325659_48616d9bc7_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-04-11T13:13:46-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/ericmorton/\">ericmorton<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/ericmorton/16927325659/\" title=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 127 HDR\"><img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7587/16927325659_48616d9bc7_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"159\" alt=\"Muleshoe Bend Bluebonnets - 127 HDR\" /><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2015-04-11T21:32:00Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (ericmorton)",
            "author_id": "31408561@N00",
            "tags": "texas hdr bluebonnets muleshoebend"
        },
        {
            "title": "DSC00435",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/laura_rivera/16906113517/",
            "media": {
                "m": "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8737/16906113517_4a9c6c7929_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-04-11T13:17:10-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/laura_rivera/\">laura_rivera<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/laura_rivera/16906113517/\" title=\"DSC00435\"><img src=\"https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8737/16906113517_4a9c6c7929_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"DSC00435\" /><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2015-04-11T21:30:26Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (laura_rivera)",
            "author_id": "20516990@N04",
            "tags": "texas bluebonnet wildflowers wildflower bluebonnets laurarivera"
        },

    ]
})
]
```

How can I make it valid?

Comment: Look at the resulting output. It doesn't look like valid JSON to me. Probably something wrong with the URL.

Comment: How can I make that into valid JSON manually?

Comment: Add `&nojsoncallback=1` to URL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563828/parsing-json-feeds-into-iphone

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  ("jsonFlickrFeed(" is not part of the JSON, of course.  It starts with the `{` character.  Otherwise it appears valid.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `nojsoncallback=1` to the end of your URL as per the documentation (bottom of this page):

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

Otherwise, the API returns `JSONP` with the callback function `jsonFlickrApi`

Comment: Are there ways in swift to convert `JSONP` to `JSON` for api’s that don’t offer `JSON`?

Comment: You'd hack it and remove the characters that you know are part of the padding, which is the last `)` or `);` at the end, and the function name and the opening `(` - e.g. `jsonFlickrApi(` in your case. But all you need to do is add `&nojsoncallback=1` to your URL and it will return you valid `JSON` - is that not working for you?

Comment: Thanks Adam! Unfortunatly even having nojsoncallback = 1 does not return valid JSON. JsonLint site still says it is invalid and iOS is not able to parse it successfully. This is really crazy!

Comment: You're incorrect. This URL - https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=texas&tagmode=any&format=json&nojsoncallback=1 - returns valid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one, it return exactly the JSON you're looking for -

https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1